# Jenkins JNLP Linux Agents - Ping Timed Out

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, azure-aks

I have been facing this issue for the past 8 months (since Dec 2019) and decided to post it here - I am connecting Jenkins Agents - Inbound TCP (JNLP) across Azure VNet and Subscriptions.

The Agents within the same VNet / Subscription as Master connect without any issue and no ping timeout issues occurs. However, Jenkins Agents residing in other Vnets and subscriptions very often get disconnected due to **Ping Timeout**. These agents are in AKS clusters, built upon `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` image and running as pods, managed by Deployments. We use `port 50000` as a static port for all JNLP connections.

The logs for Agents in other Vnet's state:

```
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:33 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /opt/workspace/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:33 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /opt/workspace/remoting
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: jenkins-slave-jmeter
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3.33
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /opt/workspace/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://jenkins.internaldomain.com/]
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkins.internaldomain.com
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      70:35:e7:e9:31:ed:a3:1f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.internaldomain.com:50000
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 70:35:e7:e9:31:ed:a3:1f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 25, 2020 12:03:35 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Jul 25, 2020 12:27:37 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.internaldomain.com/10.177.xxx.xxx:50000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1595679817121 hasn't completed by 1595680057121
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:134)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:90)

Jul 25, 2020 12:32:37 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.internaldomain.com/10.177.xxx.xxx:50000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1595680117120 hasn't completed by 1595680357121
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:134)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:90)

Jul 25, 2020 12:37:37 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.internaldomain.com/10.177.xxx.xxx:50000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1595680417120 hasn't completed by 1595680657122
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:134)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:90)

Jul 25, 2020 12:39:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:30 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Performing onReconnect operation.
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:30 PM jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$FindEffectiveRestarters$1 onReconnect
INFO: Restarting agent via jenkins.slaves.restarter.UnixSlaveRestarter@3ac9ecc9
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /opt/workspace/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /opt/workspace/remoting
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: jenkins-slave-jmeter
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3.33
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /opt/workspace/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://jenkins.internaldomain.com/]
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkins.internaldomain.com
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      70:35:e7:e9:31:ed:a3:1f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.internaldomain.com:50000
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:33 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 70:35:e7:e9:31:ed:a3:1f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 25, 2020 12:39:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
```

*ICMP Ping (Echo) is disabled as per org policies* and this blog [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ping+Thread) states that Remoting Ping is different than ICMP Ping so ICMP being disabled isn't one of the worries (that's what I think)

1. We tried by disabling Ping in Jenkins Master and Agents but that didn't work.
2. Initially we ran Master on `port 80` and it was blocked hence we suspected it to issue with non-secure port. We configured Master with SSL and on `port 443` but the issue was still present.
3. We found that Azure Idle Timeout is 4 minutes, and Jenkins default ping interval is 5 minutes (300 seconds) so I have tried setting these configuration properties:

   - **hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingIntervalSeconds** :

     > Default: 300,
     > Custom: 108

     Description: Frequency of pings between the master and agents, in seconds
   - **hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingTimeoutSeconds** :

     > Default: 240,
     > Custom: No Changes

     Description: Timeout for each ping between the master and agents, in seconds

   Still, no luck.

Has anyone faced an issue like this before, all I can find about is similar issue happened for Windows Agents

***Jenkins Agents Name, Identity, Master DNS and IP have been changed to look like generic***

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins Master and Slave could keep connection between same VNet but is not able to connect across VNet, that would mean specific port might be blocked across VNet. You will need to enable ping port network traffic across VNet using Network Security Groups (NSG). You can read about it from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview).

Once you have enabled that, you can create VM in VNet of jenkins master and try connecting to jenkins slave ping port (using telnet or similar tool). If you are able to connect that would mean NSG is not blocking the traffic otherwise NSG would be blocking the traffic.